# Is there any way to implement Stripe card widget in the Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments

Is there any way to implement Stripe card widget in the Xamarin.Forms? for Android and iOS. I want to implement the UI components of the stripe which are available in the native but are not available in the Xamarin.Forms.

Something like this?
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: You need to write xamarin bindings for the native iOS library to use it in xamarin

Comment: https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-xamarin-ios-sdk You can add this nuget package

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT is it paid solution?

Comment: @srimanreddy do you have any tutorial or something which i can use for help for implement Stripe View?

Comment: Yes,you are right.And the package for android is also available.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT first, i actually can not go for the paid solution. 2nd as much as i have studied this it seems they are using custom UI as well and then at the back they are sending the API call for the transaction. I have achieved this already. What i want is to implement the stripe view like this https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios.

Comment: @OmerObaid Example for xamarin iOS Native binding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos